# bootstrap navigation bar: location of logout button and username when logged in

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I've made navigation bar with bootstrap 4.4.1 version.
When I logged in with system, logout button and username(Welcome, (username)!) comes left.
They should go very right side like login button.
I tried to insert no-link button or ul tag or li tag, but as a length of username change, it's location changes. When I used those things and username gets more than 6 letters, then whole navbar was broken with two lines.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title></title>
<link href="http://localhost/rentcar/bootstrap- 
4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<?php  
session_start();//session starts here  
?>  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark mb-4">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.jpg" 
width="30" height="30"> KY Rentalcar</a> 
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
 target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria- 
 expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=car_price">Cars</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=selectReview">Review</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="map.php">Pickup Station</a>
      </li> 
      <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=selectChatView">
    Chat</a>
      </li>
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    ?>
    </ul>
       <a href="index.php?page=loginView">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">
        Login
        </button>
      </a>
    <?php
    }else if ($_SESSION['status']=='customer'){
    ?>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=selectMy_pageView">My 
    Information</a>
      </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php? 
   page=selectMy_reservationView">My Reservation</a>
      </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=insertReservationView">New 
    Reservation</a>
      </li>

    <ul>  
    <li class="nav-link disabled" style="color:white;">
       <?php
         if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
          echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!";
        }
       ?>
      <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
     </li>
     </ul>

      <ul>
       <a href="index.php?page=logoutDo">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">
        Logout
        </button>
      </a>
      </ul>
    <?php
    }else if ($_SESSION['status']=='admin'){
    ?>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=selectCar_typeView">Car 
    Type Management</a>
      </li> 
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php? 
    page=selectCustomerView">Customer Data</a>
       </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php? 
    page=selectReservationView">Reservation Data</a>
     </li>


    <ul>  
    <li class="nav-link disabled" style="color:white;">
       <?php
         if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
          echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!";
        }
       ?>
      <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
     </li>
     </ul>

      <ul>
       <a href="index.php?page=logoutDo">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">
        Logout
        </button>
      </a>
      </ul>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div>
   </nav>   
   <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
   ================================================== -->
   <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384- 
  q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script 
  src="http://localhost/rentcar/bootstrap-4.1.1/assets/js/vendor/jquery- 
   slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="http://localhost/rentcar/bootstrap- 
  4.1.1/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
<script src="http://localhost/rentcar/bootstrap- 
    4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```